# AWS Copilot multiple Load Balanced Web Service

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer, aws-copilot

I have deployed a Load Balanced Web Service in a copilot application. After deploying it, I added a new HTTPS / 443 listener that forwards requests to the Target Group where the ECS container is deployed:

```yaml
name: api1
type: Load Balanced Web Service

http:
  path: 'api1'
```

When I go to https://my-domain.com/api1, the requests go to my ECS container, all good.

Now I want to add a second Load Balanced Web Service:

```yaml
name: api2
type: Load Balanced Web Service

http:
  path: 'api2'
```

When I deploy it, it gets created into another Target Group and when I do https://my-domain.com/api2 the requests go to the first container (api1). I tried adding the 2nd target group to the "Forward To" rule of the Https listener, but then the requests get redirected randomly between both and I get 503 errors most of the time.

What is the correct way to deploy 2 load balanced web service within the same app? I just want to have
https://my-domain.com/api1 => api1 container
https://my-domain.com/api2 => api2 container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found the solution, I had to do on the Load Balancer:

- add the HTTPS listener that forwards to one of the Target Groups
- click on "View/edits rules" on the new HTTPS listener
- click on the + button in the navbar
- click on "+ Insert Rule" in the middle
- click on "+ Add condition"
- select "Path" and enter the path to the other service `/api2`
- click on "+ Add action"
- select "Forward to" and select the second Target Group

It would be nice to be able to do this from the copilot config but it works now